# PowerShell Calling a new .NET form

Tags: .net, forms, powershell

I'm trying to make my scripts available to end users. For this to happen they need to be able to click some buttons to launch some of the scripts we have. What would be ideally is a .NET form that shows the different categories, and upon selection of a category shows you the correct action buttons.

The problem I have is in the part **# Call Sub menu 1**, the previous form is not closed and stays visible (you can see this when you move the form on top away). Why is `$MenuBox.Close()` not working to get rid of the initial window?

Is there maybe a better way of making a menu then this way? Or is it obligated to create a new `Form` every time you need to see a new window? In a later stage, I need to add a **Back** button to for navigation purposes.

**The code:**

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$WindowTitle = 'Script center'
$Title = 'Welcome to Script Center'

# Main menu
$MenuBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$MenuBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(650,450)
$MenuBox.Text = $WindowTitle
$MenuBox.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$MenuBox.AutoSize = $False
$MenuBox.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
$MenuBox.Icon = $Icon

# AD menu
$ADBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ADBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(650,450)
$ADBox.Text = $WindowTitle
$ADBox.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$ADBox.AutoSize = $False
$ADBox.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
$ADBox.Icon = $Icon

# Main menu button 2
$ADButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ADButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(62,160)
$ADButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$ADButton1.Add_Click({
    $global:ButtonResult = 'Result: AD Button 1'
    $MenuBox.Close()
})
$ADButton1.Text = 'AD Button 1'
$ADButton1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,1)
$ADBox.Controls.Add($ADButton1)

# Main menu Header Text
$MenuHeader = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MenuHeader.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",14,1,3,1)
$MenuHeader.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(118,20)
$MenuHeader.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,40) 
$MenuHeader.Text = $Title
$MenuHeader.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::TopCenter
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($MenuHeader)

# Main menu
$BoxLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$BoxLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",10,0,3,1)
$BoxLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60) 
$BoxLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(680,20) 
$BoxLabel.Text = 'Select the category:'
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($BoxLabel)

# Main menu button 1
$Button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(62,100)
$Button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$Button2.Add_Click({
    # Call Sub menu 1
    $MenuBox.Close()
    $ADBox.Topmost = $True
    $ADBox.Add_Shown({$ADBox.Activate()})
    [void] $ADBox.ShowDialog()
})
$Button2.Text = 'Active directory'
$Button2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,1)
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($Button2)

# Main menu button 2
$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(62,160)
$Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$Button1.Add_Click({
    $global:ButtonResult = 'Result: Button 2'
    $MenuBox.Close()
})
$Button1.Text = 'Files and Folders'
$Button1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,1)
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($Button1)

# Exit Button
$ExitButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ExitButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(540,370)
$ExitButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$ExitButton.Text = 'Exit'
$ExitButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",11,0,3,1)
$ExitButton.Add_Click({
    Remove-Item "$WorkingDirectory\Temp\*.*" -Force
    $MenuBox.Close()
})
$MenuBox.Controls.Add($ExitButton)

# Show Menu
$MenuBox.Topmost = $True
$MenuBox.Add_Shown({$MenuBox.Activate()})
[void] $MenuBox.ShowDialog()
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the `$MenuBox` form to close with the Dispose() method after invoking Close():

```
$Button2.Add_Click({
    # Call Sub menu 1
    $MenuBox.Close()
    $MenuBox.Dispose()
    $ADBox.Topmost = $True
    $ADBox.Add_Shown({$ADBox.Activate()})
    [void] $ADBox.ShowDialog()
})
```